# Laravel doesn't recognize "index" as the default action

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

When I go to http://example.com/clients , Laravel response 404 Error , but when I go to http://example.com/clients/index , Laravel render the right view and run the index action.

My .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My controller :

```
<?php

class Clients_Controller extends Base_Controller 
{


     public function action_index()
    {
            return View::make('clients.clients');
    }



}
```

My Routes.php

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect(),'home.index');
```

Comment: Have you tried the alternate `.htaccess` as described here: http://laravel.com/docs/install#cleaner-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed :

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect(),'home.index');
```

and replace it by :

```
Route::controller('clients');
```

Answer (score 0):

To map all the controllers and actions you have to remove the 'home.index'.

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```

Comment: It wouldn't affect it, the second parameter is just to set the default controller/action for the app.